# Cypress - waiting for all jQuery requests to finish before proceeding to next step

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have come from a Selenium/Python background and I'm now learning Cypress.

In a nutshell, we have a visual regression tool that has to wait for everything on the page to completely load prior to taking a screenshot.

In my previous framework, I was able to use the following code to wait for a page to completely load that had jQuery requests and it worked.

```
def wait_for_page_to_load(self):
        """
        Waits for page to fully load
        """
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10, 0.25)
            wait.until(
                lambda driver: driver.execute_script(
                    "return (window.jQuery != null) && (jQuery.active === 0);"
                )
            )
            self.log.info("Page has finished loading")
        except:
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            self.log.error(
                "### Exception occurred whilst waiting for page to load: %s", e
            )
```

Now that I am using Cypress, I don't know how to basically run the return line.  I've searched google but so far no good.

I've played around with the following but no joy.

```
pageLoaded() {
        Cypress.$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may call the window object using cypress command [`cy.window()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/window#Syntax).

```js
cy.window().then(win => {
    // do something with win
});
```

But I believe it would be best to use commands [`cy.intercept()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Syntax) with [`cy.wait`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait)

```js
// before the start of your test:
cy.intercept('GET', '/path/to/api/calls/1').as('apiCall1');

// During your test:
cy.visit('yourUrl');
cy.wait('@apiCall1');
```